# Button value as a condition of conditionalpanel in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I have a form that once all performed has a "Done" button. Once the user clicks that "Done" button, I want to display instead of the form, a `shinydashboard`.

To do this, I thought of two `conditionalPanel`s and since a button has a value, if this value is 0, show the form and otherwise show the `shinydashboard`. My problem is that the condition, does not work.

The whole code is too large to reproduce so the main idea is this:

```
#server.R

library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$frontEnd <- renderUI(
    fluidPage(
      input$buton,
      conditionalPanel("input$buton == 0",p("I'm a form")),
      conditionalPanel("input$buton > 0", p("I'm a dashboard"))
    )
  )
})



#UI.r
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  actionButton("buton","click me"),
  htmlOutput("frontEnd")
))
```

Any idea why does not take the value of the button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
conditionalPanel(condition = "input.buton == 0", p("I'm a form")),
conditionalPanel(condition = "input.buton > 0", p("I'm a dashboard"))
```

The condition argument is a [javascript expression](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.5/conditionalPanel.html).